# Google maps: Check if my location is within my radius

Tags: api, google-maps, location, maps, marker

I'm currently working with the google maps API and i'm fairly new.
But I need to check of my current location is within the radius of my marker, so i can execute a function.

Does anyone know how I can check that?

Comment: What have you tried? What does the code for your map look like?  What does the code for the marker look like?  What is the "radius" of your marker?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a constant radius
2. Calculate distance between your location and your markers location using this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/#spherical
3. Check if distance <= radius